# Import JSON file via RockMongo on OpenShift is not working

Tags: json, mongodb, import, openshift

I has setup a gear with Tomcat, MongoDB and RockMongo on OpenShift. I want to fill a collection with about 40000 documents via a JSON file. It works fine on my local machine with the commandline 'mongoimport'. Via RockMongo, I choose the collection where I want to import it, and then open the file. It looks fine on the first moment, but the documents are not there :-(

Comment: Does it timeout or throw some sort of error? Have you looked into rockmongo or mongodb log files. See this KB (https://www.openshift.com/faq/how-to-troubleshoot-application-issues-using-logs)  on how to check log files. If you are comfortable using mongoimport command, try importing with it. Troubleshooting issues will be easier with mongoimport.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ssh'ing into your gear and running the `mongoimport` command directly to import your collection.